# split binary file into chunks upload / download

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, file-upload, couchdb

I am using couchdb for some reason as a content mangment to upload files as binary data,
there is no GridFs support like mongo db to upload large files, so i need to upload files as chunks then retreive them as one file

here is my code

```
public string InsertDataToCouchDb(string dbName, string id, string filename, byte[] image)
        {
            var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CouchDb"].ConnectionString;
            using (var db = new MyCouchClient(connection, dbName))
            {

                // HERE I NEED TO UPLOAD MY IMAGE BYTE[] AS CHUNKS 
                var artist = new couchdb
                {
                    _id = id,
                    filename = filename,
                    Image = image
                };

                var response = db.Entities.PutAsync(artist);
                return response.Result.Content._id;
            }

        }


 public byte[] FetchDataFromCouchDb(string dbName, string id)
        {
            var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CouchDb"].ConnectionString;
            using (var db = new MyCouchClient(connection, dbName))
            {
                //HERE I NEED TO RETRIVE MY FULL IMAGE[] FROM CHUNKS
                var test = db.Documents.GetAsync(id, null);
                var doc = db.Serializer.Deserialize<couchdb>(test.Result.Content);
                return doc.Image;
            }
        }
```

THANK YOU

Comment: i'm not familiar with couchdb but i suppose you would need an overload of the `PutAsync()` method where it would take in some sort of stream instead of an already populated object. if there's no such thing in couchdb, then you'd have to build your own gridFS like system where you yourself would break the image file in to pieces and store it in the db. have a look at mongodb driver source code to see how they do it.

Comment: hope you've figured out how to do this. in any case, i implemented something like this for my mongodb library. you can see the source code [here](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/blob/master/MongoDB.Entities/Utilities/FileEntity.cs#L149). the resulting api can be seen [here](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/wiki/12.-File-Storage)

Comment: thank you , i will try to apply that to my case couchdb, and i will let you know if that works.